# DiffUtil.ItemCallback - define as a companion object or as a class?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter, android-diffutils

I'm currently learning Kotlin through the Kotlin Android Developer program from Udacity. There's two sample apps using DiffUtil.ItemCallback, but declare it in different ways. Both sample apps use a ListAdapter, however one declares the DiffUtil like this: `companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MarsProperty>()`

while the other like this: `class SleepNightDiffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<SleepNight>()`

Both DiffUtils are passed as parameters to the ListAdapter, with the only difference being that in the case of the class implementation, it has to be initialised:

```
class PhotoGridAdapter : ListAdapter<MarsProperty, PhotoGridAdapter.ViewHolder>(DiffCallback)
class SleepNightAdapter : ListAdapter<SleepNight, SleepNightAdapter.ViewHolder>(SleepNightDiffCallback())
```

The only difference between those sample apps is that one downloads and shows images from the internet (the one with the PhotoGridAdapter), while the other shows data from a database, so
my question is: Is one implementation *preferred* compared to the other? Are there any performance differences between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a matter of opinion. Mine is that the callback should be an `object`, or anonymous object, but not a `companion object`.

All it's doing is comparing properties of two objects. It doesn't have to hold any state. So it makes sense for it to be a singleton `object` rather than a `class` that you have to instantiate. Whether you define it as a named singleton `object` or define in place as an anonymous object assigned to a property doesn't make much different in communicating intent.

But it doesn't make sense to me to make it a `companion`. It's already nested and has a name. All `companion` does is suggest that you should need to call its functions directly and that the name `PhotoGridAdapter` should also be thought of as a callback. For instance, it enables you to pass the name `PhotoGridAdapter` to some other adapter as its DiffUtil callback, which is nonsensical. The only reason it might possibly make sense is if you also want to use it as a utility for comparing items, so you could call functions like `PhotoGridAdapter.areContentsTheSame` directly. However, I don't think this is likely. Usually, the contents of the callback's functions are either very trivial like passing through `equals()` or they are very specific to the nature of updating the displayed list.